# Sentry configuration with Amazon SES

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, sentry

There seems to be nothing on the web about this...

How do you parametrize sentry.conf.py to use Amazon SES backend for emails?

Right now, in a Django project, we use:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'

AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Sentry is a bit different, anyone has insights?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 5):

You can configure sentry to send emails using a SMTP Server and you can obtain SMTP credentials from SES.

To set up SES for using the SMTP interface follow this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html

Then configure your sentry installation to use those credentials (s. https://docs.sentry.io/server/config/#mail)

Example `config.yml`:

```
mail.backend: 'smtp'
mail.host: 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
mail.port: 587
mail.username: 'myuser'
mail.password: 'mypassword'
mail.use-tls: true
# The email address to send on behalf of
mail.from: 'sentry@example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration with [django-amazon-ses](https://github.com/azavea/django-amazon-ses) (different from [django-ses](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses)), without SMTP credentials, is:

In `sentry/config.yml` :

```yaml
mail.backend: 'django_amazon_ses.EmailBackend'
mail.from: 'from@example.com'

# Comment or delete the other `mail.*` options
```

In `sentry/sentry.conf.py` , if region is not `us-east-1`:

```py
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "eu-west-1"
```

In `sentry/enhance-image.sh` (since [v22.6.0](https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted/releases)):

```bash
pip install django-amazon-ses
```

Then restart Sentry as usual with `./install.sh` and `docker compose up -d`

PS: assuming the instance or the default profile has the IAM `ses:SendEmail` permission.